# MJPEG data doesn't have SOI marker. What kind of mjpeg I'm dealing with?

Tags: jpeg, gstreamer, vlc, mjpeg, live555

I'm writing a simple MJPEG streamer in Java.

Since it has very specific application, I had to reverse engineer the rtp packets sent by the GStreamer using the Wireshark sniffer. The GStreamer, in turn, just restreams the mjpeg avi file taken from specific camera.

The first and the most straightforward way is to prepare packets as an array of data and send them to the consumer, particularly VLC player, that uses live555 library. I'm populating the rtp headers well, so the internal payload is hardcoded; in my experiment VLC successfully displays the encoded screen, i.e. it decodes the hardcoded rtp payload well.

So, that is the value of first two packets payload (from total 25) in hex view:

```
String[] hexArray =
        {
                    "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", //1
                    "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", //2
```

According to the spec, the first bytes of the first packet are:

```
0000000000ffa05a
```

this is Type-specific, Fragment Offset, Type, Q, Width, Height, MBZ, Precision, Length

the next data starting with 0000008010 and ending with 636363 is Quantization Table 128 bytes long.

So, the question is what is the data starting right after it?

```
ad8a5a0029
```

According to specs, no one of it can be recognized as possible JPEG marker, so the question is what is the encoding used and how can I encode the image I like with this particular encoding?

Attempt to encode on the manner of http://www.media.mit.edu/pia/Research/deepview/src/JpegEncoder.java works well for the jpeg files, but is not decoded with VLC's live555.